# Htmlextender disappeared vbs2012

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I had added HTML extender to the form and it was working fine. Now when I try to add confirmbutton extender it gives me an error saying "unknown server tag ....". When I remove the confirmbutton extender it is fine. Can it be cached? Also now I don't see it in my AjaxTookKit either. I changed from scriptmanager to ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager in the master file. I added the following in aspx page.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="HTMLEditor" %>
```

I have the following in config file.

```
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like HTML extender is being dropped. I am trying to use the AjaxControlToolKit - Editor. I added this in the Edit template and in the itemtemplate I have textbox. The edittemplate editor does not bind to the data nor does it let me enter any text.

```
<custom:CustomEditor runat="server" ID="txtBanNotes" Content='<%# Bind("BannedInfo") %>' Width="37em" Height="10em"/>
```